# Error 1001 could not find a part of the path 'c:\program files\

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-project

VS2010, Setup project; it worked fine before. Due to re-branding, I change assembly name, product name, compnay name, etc. If I do a new install, it works. but if I install on top of previous version, I get the error which says

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\old Company Name\old Product Name\CustomActions.InstallState'.

I have custom action in install step. I tried to put Primary output to Commit step, which gives the same error.  custom actionData is /filepath="[TARGETDIR]install.xls"